# Magento 2 : setOrder not working in collection

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.2.2

In my custom collection `$career_collection->setOrder('career_id','ASC');` not working.

My function is below

```
public function getAllCareers(){

    $Careers = $this->_careersFactory->create();
    $career_collection = $Careers->getCollection();
    $career_collection->addFieldToFilter('active',1)->setOrder('career_id','ASC');
    //$career_collection->setOrder('career_id','ASC');

    echo $career_collection->getSelect(); exit;
    return $career_collection;
}
```

`getSelect` return the query like below

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `e25_careers` AS `main_table` WHERE (`active` = '1').
```

What is the wrong i am doing here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct method

```
$career_collection->addFieldToFilter('active',1)->setOrder('career_id','ASC');
```

If it is not showing in query. just simply add **load();**

```
$career_collection->addFieldToFilter('active',1)->setOrder('career_id','ASC')->load();
```

Then it will show complete query.

Comment: Thanks..Working

Answer (score 3):

You can try below way:

```
$career_collection->getSelect()->order('career_id ASC');
```

Comment: yes this is working to get the query.But how can i return the collection with this order by query.if i add lik ethis $career_collection->Order('career_id ASC'); its not working

Answer (score 0):

I was facing syntax error, so resolved it by just putting single quotes

```
$collection->setOrder('career_id','ASC');
```